# Add a namespace in a KML document in Python LXML

Tags: python, namespaces, lxml

I am reading this reference on Google Extension:

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml

Since I need to use the Element with a gx prefix gx:drawOrder, I need to update the namespaces to:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
  xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
```

I have tried first to identify the Element, then used .set, but didn't work.

Could anyone please help?

This is what the first 2 lines of my KML look like:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
```

I thought it would be a simple job to change the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a new element that is bound to another namespace, a declaration for that namespace will be inserted automatically when the XML file is serialized. By default, the declaration does not appear on the root element and the prefix may not be what you want.

Demo:

```
from lxml import etree

# Parse original XML
orig_xml = '<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"/>'
root = etree.fromstring(orig_xml)

ns = "http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"

# Add new element in other namespace as child of root
test = etree.SubElement(root, etree.QName(ns, "drawOrder"))

print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True).decode())
```

Output:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <ns0:drawOrder xmlns:ns0="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"/>
</kml>
```

This is a perfectly fine, well-formed XML document, but it probably isn't exactly what you want. That can be fixed by using [`cleanup_namespaces()`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#cleanup_namespaces). Add the following line before the `print()` call:

```
etree.cleanup_namespaces(root, top_nsmap={"gx": ns})
```

New output:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
  <gx:drawOrder/>
</kml>
```